# Why isn't applied CSS selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.colored p{
   color: red;
}


article > .colored{
   color:powderblue;
}

.blue{
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="colored">
      <p>hello</p>
      <p class="blue">hello</p>
      <div>
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <article>
      <div class="colored">hello</div>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't the blue selector applied???
It's applied when I changed it(p.blue).
I don`t know the difference between first case and second case ..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: `.colored p` has a greater specificity than `.blue` and overrides it

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in second case is, p tag have parent class *colored* and that is why it is applying css of parent class to second p tag. Even though you have provided class *blue* but still parent class have high precedence.

You can use *!important* override precedence for color property in class blue. The *!important* instruction has the highest precedence of all precedence factors.

```css
.colored p{
   color: red;
}


article > .colored{
   color:powderblue;
}

.blue{
   color: green!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="colored">
      <p>hello</p>
      <p class="blue">hello</p>
      <div>
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <article>
      <div class="colored">hello</div>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you. You made me understand :)